# Node.js Await Async with util class function

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am fairly new to Node.js and I am trying to pick it up with Koa.js framework.

I am struggling to understand why the index.js -> console.log run even if I have the await in the value.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

index.js

```
router.get('getValue','/display',async (ctx) => {
   var myUtilfunction = require('../util')
   var result = await myUtilfunction.getData()
   console.log(result)
}
```

util.js

```
async function getData(){
    var customObject =[]
    var standardObject =[]
    conn.describeGlobal(function (err,res){
    if (err){return console.error(err)}
    console.log('No of Objects ' + res.sobjects.length)
    res.sobjects.forEach(function(sobject){
        if (sobject.custom){

            customObject.push(sobject)
        }else{

            standardObject.push(sobject)
        }
    })
    console.log("Done")
})
return [customObject, standardObject] 
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it? `getData` returns immediately

Comment: there's a bunch of codes in getData that calls api

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Not sure if the above make is good enough for the minimal reproducible example

Comment: Async functions don't have any magic to know when plain asynchronous operations (not using promises) inside them are done.  So, when you try to `await` your function call, it doesn't wait for anything.  You will have to promisify `conn.describeGlobal()` and then you can await it inside the async function where you call it and then your async function call itself can be awaited and it will wait for `conn.describeGlobal()` to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

> await,  works  inside async functions

```
router.get('getValue','/display', async (ctx) => {
       var myUtilfunction = require('../util')
       var result = await myUtilfunction.getData();
       console.log(result)
    });


    function getData(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve('result goes here');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. As be the code above, i added my api call before the resolve() and return using the resolve('result goes here')

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the function is async for the await to work.

Something like this:

```
router.get('getValue','/display', async (ctx) => {
   var myUtilfunction = require('../util')
   var result = await myUtilfunction.getData()
   console.log(result)
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

In your function getData(), I think you've missplaced your return statement. The return statement should be placed inside the callback function used for conn.describeGlobal().

As you actually write your getData(), the conn.describeGlobal() call seems to be an asynchronous treatment, so the return statement placed outside is probably executed before you pushed something in your arrays.

The consequence is that your router get an empty response from your getData() function then the promise made by await keyword is resolved with an empty answer.